# Replacement for Acrobat method AFormAutLib.setButtonIcon

Tags: c#, pdf

An existing process uses the Adobe Acrobat COM object AFormAutLib to open and fill form items.  There are over 500 forms, and they all have a form field of type Button at the top.  The method AFormAutLib.setButtonIcon is used to set the path of another PDF file to be used as the image on the button.

I am looking for an alternative.  I have looked at iTextSharp, activePDF Tookit, and others, but have been unable to find anything that can replace this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use activePDF Toolkit in a different way...

```
APToolkitNET.FieldInfo myFI = aTK.FieldInfo(x.Key.ToString(),1);
aTK.PrintImage(logoPath, myFI.Left, myFI.Bottom, myFI.Width, myFI.Height, true, 1);
aTK.DeleteFormField(x.Key.ToString());
```

The button had the right location and dimensions, so the FieldInfo class is used to get those values.  Then PrintImage is called with the path to the image and the locations, before the button is deleted.